# Track onclick actions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I need to build Google Chrome plugin, what will track all clicks on all links on all pages.

After click on link, instead of page opening plugin must catch click, plugin must obtain href attribute of the clicked link, change something in this URL and open page with new, changed URL.

Is it possible to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) you can pass your own JS library into any (or particular) page, intersect clicks and prevent defaults (with regular JS API) and finally you can pass link back to the background page and use [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) API to open the window.